# How to find first day of multi-day event on monthly basis?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with daily snapshot data that has a date and amount column. I'm converting this to a monthly snapshot table. Every record in this monthly table should look like what you see in the table below at 31-01.

If on the last day of the month the amount is negative, amount_negative_lastday_of_month = True. The part I can't figure out is the first_date_negative_amount. If the amount_negative_lastday_of_month = True, I want to get the first day on which the amount became negative for that specific period where the amount was negative. In the table below that would be 28-01-2021.

If this period of amount < 0 continuous on until the end of February, we will see the exact same in the Feb. monthly snapshot where amount_negative_lastday_of_month = True and amount_negative_lastday_of_month = 28-01-2021.

If this period of negative amount is over, and in a few months a new period of negative amount begins, I want to do the same again.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to group/window my data by varying periods of time where a certain condition is met (amount < 0).

How can I query this?

| date | amount | last_day_of_month | amount_negative_lastday | first_date_negative_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26-1-2021 | -10 |  |  |  |
| 27-1-2021 | 200 |  |  |  |
| 28-1-2021 | -200 |  |  |  |
| 29-1-2021 | -200 |  |  |  |
| 30-1-2021 | -200 |  |  |  |
| 31-1-2021 | -100 | 31-1-2021 | TRUE | 28-1-2021 |
| 1-2-2021 | -122 |  |  |  |
| 2-2-2021 | -222 |  |  |  |
| 3-2-2021 | -322 |  |  |  |

Comment: If on February 15 you have 1 day of positive amount, but February 16 is again negative and other February dates are negative (so the last Feb day is also negative), what do you have in Feb snapshot, column first_date_negative_amount? Is is Feb 16 or Jan 28?

Comment: Do you need to keep day-by-day rows, or you only want to have month dates?